# Zustand get state from another Zustand store

Tags: reactjs, store, state-management, react-state-management, zustand

*I have created 2 Zustand stores in react application, one is called UserStore, and the other is called SettingsStore, how can I get the state from UserStore to SettingsStore? *

```
import create from 'zustand';

const UserStore = (set, get) => ({

user: {},

});
```

*I want to use this "user" variable to my other store called SettingsStore*

```
import create from 'zustand';

const SettingsStore = (set, get) => ({



});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must import UserStore in SettingStore file, and then use `UserStore.getState().user`

Answer (score 7):

You can import the store within the other store and retrieve the state via the `.getState()` function.

```
import create from "zustand";

const useUserState = create((set, get) => ({
  userId: undefined,
}));

const useSettingState = create((set, get) => ({
  updateSetting: (user) => {
    const userId = useUserState.getState().userId;
    // do something with userId
  },
}));
```

Comment: Quite cool feature, this way you can import store methods from separate files too. At first could not find it in the official docs,I managed to find it only after I had seen it here, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom hook

```
const useCustomHook = () => {
   const [userId ] = useUserStore(state => [state.userId]);
   const [ updateSetting ] = useSettingStore(state => [state.updateSetting])
      
       useEffect(() => {
       ///// yo can use useeffect otherwisw
       },[]);
    
       const result = updateSetting(user,userId)
    
       
       return result;
    
    
     }
    
    export { useCustomHook, ...}
```